# Pagination for search results of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination

I'm trying to display numbered pagination for search results of a custom post type. Basically a search form allows users to search a custom post type by 2 different taxonomies and then the results are displayed on a page template. I want to display 10 posts per page.

I've managed to get the pagination to work, but only if I hard code the  tag and I can't seem to figure out how to get it to automatically add in the links depending on how many pages of results there are.

Pastebin of page template code - http://pastebin.com/XpKKCdw9

Comment: before we talk about your pagination, what happen with your custom page if both parameter `location` and `service` are not set yet?

Comment: Please do not use external service to host code. If the paste is removed, all context of your question is lost. It also p!$$ people off as it is really irritating having to open multiple browser windoows just to read one post. I personally just skip such questions and do not even look at them ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your paged arg in your $args array:

```
$listing_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'business',
    'posts_per_page'    => 10,
    'meta_key'          => 'listing_num',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'offset'            => ($paged -1) * 10,
    'paged'             => $paged, // <- tell the query what page we are on.
    'tax_query'         => ......etc
);
```

And then use the `pageinate_links` function, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links to populate the links to the next/prev pages.

Example from the codex on how to use it with a custom query:

```
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
) );
```